# "CDaoDatabase::Open() " function is not opening ".accdb " file .why?

Tags: database, visual-c++

I need to Open a ".accdb " file from my vc++ project .
I am using  "CDaoDatabase::Open()" to open database but it is not opening ".accdb " file. ".mdb" are opening well .what can i do ?

Comment: I have access 2007 installed on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Mfc dao (via jet database engine) cannot directly read accdb file as the accdb is a newer format. See this article for comprehensive overview http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc811599(v=office.12).aspx

You should be able to change your connect string to be a odbc path as a workaround. The article shows several examples of different techniques under the ODBC heading.

Comment: earlier i was able to do that using ''CDaoDatabase class but then i decompiled  my database file and every thing changed.now my vc++ code cant open my accdb file.i installed new jet driver  but still same problem  .

Comment: Try using CDatabase rather than CDaoDatabase, see worked examples in the microsoft doc. Annoying I know, but eventually technologies need to get replaced.

Comment: thanx for ur reply.i learnt that i can create .accdb file  with CDAO.. but cant open already created by access 2007 .so  i am using files " CDAO... created ones".have u worked on access database ?